# Is there a published RQ decomposition column-major algorthm?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am refactoring an existing algorithm where where a RQ decomposition (as opposed to the more common QR) would be rather useful.

Most common books on the subject (e.g. [Golub and Van Loan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0801854148)) discuss QR extensively and provide algorithms for common implementations (e.g. Algorithm 5.2.1 for Householder or Algorithm 5.2.5 for Modified Gram Schmidt).

Unfortunately, it does not discuss RQ, except for a small note regarding LAPACK routines. Wikipedia suggests that the [differences are trivial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Relation%20to%20RQ%20decomposition), where "RQ decomposition is Gram–Schmidt orthogonalization of rows of A, started from the last row".

Since the matrices I am working on are column-major, this is not especially attractive.

Are there well-known column-major implementations of RQ, especially using MGS or Householder?  Or even if there is some blocking algorithm that is efficient on column data?

Other details:
This particular problem does not require pivoting, and I only need R - I do not need Q.

Comment: Have you considered transposing the matrix as a preprocessing step? Even if you just do it before and after the algorithm, it is much cheaper than QR / RQ factorization itself.